# Where to set environmental variables in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, variables

In my development I wish to hit a development URL when im testing but when the app is run on my iPhone, I want it to run on production URL. How do I get about setting this in Xcode?

Almost seems like I need to be able to set environmental variables (which in this case are different URLs).

Where do I set these up? Please hand hold me on the answer as I am fairly new

Thanks

Comment: Here are a few different approaches: http://qualitycoding.org/production-url/

Comment: I generally set it in the build configuration. You can do additional things like changing the display name/bundle ID (this allows both "production" and "development" builds to be installed on the same phone, and means you can tell roughly what's installed without bringing up a settings view).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  My preferred method is to create a file called Constants.h that looks like this:

```
//
//  Constants.h
//

#ifndef Constants_h
#define Constants_h

#pragma mark - Instances
#ifdef DEVELOPMENT
#define ROOT_URL @"http://127.0.0.1:8000"
#endif

#ifdef STAGING
#define ROOT_URL @"http://staging.example.com"
#endif

#ifdef PRODUCTION
#define ROOT_URL @"http://production.example.com"
#endif
```

Then, I just include it in my *-Prefix.pch file like this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Constants.h"
#endif
```

In your build settings, set DEVELOPMENT, or STAGING, or PRODUCTION = 1.

Now you can access things like ROOT_URL anywhere in your project.

Good luck!

Comment: recall (especially if you have a slow machine and/or a large project) that changes to the precompiled header will cause a recompile of everything. while the values of these URLs should be nicely encapsulated into one file (though the values of DEVELOPMENT/STAGING/PRODUCTION may not be).

Comment: +1 for importing it in Prefix.pch. Works well when sharing code.

Comment: also how do you set up devleopment or staging equals to true,cannot seem to find the field in build setting

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the `#define` method as well.  For those less familiar, those are pre-processor directives and are set even before the compiler gets hold of the code.

`Environment variables` are set at runtime of the program, and can be manipulated in the `scheme editor` of Xcode 4.x+.  You could set up different schemes to hit different testing environments.

To access an environment variable at runtime from within your code, use the following:

```
NSString *url = @"http://standardurl.com";
NSDictionary *env = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
NSString *overrideURL = [env valueForKey:@"url"];
if (overrideURL != nil)
  url = overrideURL;
```

Comment: Here's a helpful macro that you can add to your Prefix.pch file: `#define ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_DEFINED(v)  ([[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] valueForKey:v] ? YES : NO)` This lets you add environment variables in Xcode's scheme editor, and toggle them on/off using the checkbox to change your code at runtime. To use this macro: `if (ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_DEFINED(@"ENV_VAR_NAME")) { ... }`

Answer (score -1):

You can also set the different URLs in your plist file by adding new String rows if you don't want to use a constants file.

(Not much to be gained here though I admit but depends on where you prefer to set up your urls)

In your myApp-plist file add new rows like this:

"DevelopmentEndpoint" "String" "http://development.endpoint.com"

"ProductionEndpoint" "String" "http://production.endpoint.com"

In your code:

```
// Get endpoint from main bundle
#ifdef DEVELOPMENT
    NSString *endpoint = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"DevelopmentEndpoint"];
#else
    NSString *endpoint = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"ProductionEndpoint"];
#endif
```

In your build settings add DEVELOPMENT under the "Preprocessor Macros" section for Debug or Release etc.

Comment: @tc Very valid point. I wasn't considering security. I suggest others follow Erik's advice.

Comment: At best it's a (security-through-)obscurity problem (dev URLs tend to be easily guessable); it mostly just seems untidy to embed dev data in a production build.